# Add elements in RDD by .filter or create method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to filter a .txt file to create RDD and generate statistics.
The filter method (.filter) permitted me to create RDD but I'm limiting because my competences are very limited.

Il would like to count the number of words that contain:

```
special characters >=3
uppercase >=1
lowercase >=1
```

Example filter utilisation:

```
   scala> val data = sc.textFile("file.txt") 
   scala> val specialChars = List('*', '@', '&', '=', '#', '?', '!', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', ' ', ',', '_', '$', '"', '[', ']', ';', ''', '(', ')', '.', '/') 
   scala> val upper = List('A' to 'Z')
   scala> val lower = List('a' to 'z')           
   scala> val data_low = data.filter(_.length < 13).filter(line => !specialChars.exists(char => line.contains(char)))
```

Here is my other approach but I don't know how to implement the result (here illustrated by println) in a RDD.

```
scala> for (line <- data) {
     | var spe_sum = 0;
     | for (c <- specialChars) {
     | spe_sum = spe_sum + line.count(_ == c);
     | }
     | if (spe_sum >= 3 & nombre.exists(char => line.contains(char)) & maj.exists(char => line.contains(char)) & minus.exists(char => line.contains(char))) {
     | println(line);
     | }
     | }
```

Is it possible to execute my code in a .filter or write .filter that do the same result?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

The `filter` method loops over the List you supply, and tests each element of the collection with the function you supply. Your function must return `true` or `false`, and `filter` returns the list elements where your function returns `true`. So, basically, you cannot use filter to count the elements in a collection.

A way to achieve your result is the following

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = // load your RDD and tokenize each word
val specialChars = List('*', '@', '&', '=', '#', '?', '!', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', ' ', ',', '_', '$', '"', '[', ']', ';', ''', '(', ')', '.', '/')
val upper = ('A' to 'Z')
val lower = ('a' to 'z')

// count the words satysfying all constraints
rdd.map(_.toList) // map each word to a list of chars
   .filter(x => specialChars.intersect(x).size > 2 && upper.intersect(x).nonEmpty && lower.intersect(x).nonEmpty)
   .count()

// count the words that satisfies at least a constraint
rdd.map(_.toList)
   .map(x => // map each word to a tuple of three elements, each element is to 1 if it satisfies the respective constraint
             (if (specialChars.intersect(x).size > 2) 1 else 0, // check the intersection with special characters
              if (upper.intersect(x).nonEmpty) 1 else 0,  // check the intersection with upper-case characters
              if (lower.intersect(x).nonEmpty) 1 else 0)) // check the intersection with lower-case characters
   .reduce((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3)) // sum up the results
```

The first element of the resulting tuple is the number of lines containing more than 3 special characters, the second is the number of lines containing at least an upper case character, the third is the number of lines containing at least a lower case character.

Comment: Waou, it's very more clear thanks you. `.intersect()` it's very useful.

Comment: If this is a proper solution to your problem, then you should accept this as an answer :)  ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))